# sitecore rocks query syntax

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

Started using the query analyzer in sitecore recently, but I am wondering if there is a way to dig deeper than querying by id, name, template, path, etc.

Such as querying by `item["mycustomerfield"] = 'something specific'`.  sitecore rocks is in ctp and the documentation is still coming around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do lots of things with the Query Analyzer.

John West has [a nice introduction here](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/07/Sitecore-Rocks-Queries.aspx).

Other than that, using the Help keyword can give you some pointers. If you type `help select` you get some detailed help on the `select` keyword - including the EBNF syntax.

You can also use the scripting commands from the Sitecore Explorer: Tools | Script | Select.

Here are an example:

Select Title and Text fields from all items under /sitecore/content that uses the Sample Item template.

```
select @title, @text from /sitecore/content//*[@@templatekey = 'sample item']
```

Notice the `@@` before the system attribute templatekey.

Other than that you should be familiar with identifier escaping. Since Sitecore field names may contain spaces, you have to enclose them in `##`.

This selects the field Long Text from home:

```
select @#Long Text# from /sitecore/content/Home
```